# Notice: Undefined index php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola estoy tratando de enviar datos a un procedimiento almacenado en mysql cuando envio los datos al php me sale los errores de la imagen

este es el formulario en html:

```
<form method="post" action="llamada.php" name="formulario">

<input type="text" required id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre"> </br></br>

<input type="text" required id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido"> </br></br>

<input type="text" required id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="nombre de usuario"> </br></br>

<input type="password" required id="clave" name="clave" placeholder="contraseña"> </br></br>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

este el codigo php que recibe los datos del formulario y los enviar al procedimiento almacenado:

```
require("coneccion/conexion.php");

print("Coneccion exitosa </br>");

$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$apellido= $_POST["apellido"];
$usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
$clave= $_POST["clave"];

print "$nombre, $apellido, $usuario, $clave";

$datos= array($nombre, $apellido, $usuario, $clave);
$procedimiento= $l->prepare("CALL ingresarusuario(?, ?, ?, ?)");
$procedimiento->bind_param("ssss", $datos[$nombre], $datos[$apellido], $datos[$usuario], $datos[$clave]);
$procedimiento->execute();
$procedimiento->close();
$l->close();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias utilizar isset, para saber si una variable esta definida y no es null, por ejemplo: $nombre = isset($_POST["nombre"]) ? $_POST["nombre"] : null ; [Referencia](http://php.net/isset)

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿en qué carpeta está el archivo de tu formulario HTML? Los `name` están bien, por lo que puede ser problema de archivo equivocado. Otra cosa: no entiendo por qué haces esto: `$datos= array($nombre, $apellido, $usuario, $clave);` y luego esto: `$procedimiento->bind_param("ssss", $datos[$nombre], $datos[$apellido], $datos[$usuario], $datos[$clave]);` cuando es más simple hacer los siguiente: **`$procedimiento->bind_param("ssss", $nombre, $apellido, $usuario, $clave);`** La simplicidad es importante. Evita acciones innecesarias que sólo recargan el código.

Comment: Si el formulario está en el mismo archivo `llamada.php`, haz de saber que debe estar al principio y el código PHP después. Y en el atributo `action` deberías poner esto `action="#"`. De todos modos, lo mejor sería usar Ajax para recibir/procesar/devolver los datos entre el cliente y el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en esta línea:

```
$procedimiento->bind_param("ssss", $datos[$nombre], $datos[$apellido], $datos[$usuario], $datos[$clave]);
```

Como el array está definido así:

```
$datos= array($nombre, $apellido, $usuario, $clave);
```

El array `datos` es en realidad esto:

```
[ 0 => $nombre, 1 => $apellido, 2 => $usuario, 3 => $clave]
```

Si quieres sacar los valores como, por ejemplo, `$datos['nombre']` tienes que escribir esos índices:

```
$datos= array('nombre' => $nombre, 'apellido' => $apellido, 'usuario' => $usuario, 'clave' => $clave);
```

Luedo podrás sacar los datos como `$datos['nombre']`, `$datos['apellido']`, etc. O simplemente puedes usar `$_POST[indice]`.

Nota que el índice no es `$nombre` si no que un string: `'nombre`', en ese caso.